# Site crawler returning multiple 404s from a single page where an internal href is appened at the end of the url? See body for context

Tags: seo, http-status-code-404, google-crawlers

I'm not sure how to best describe this but we have a community website for builders and it's using Elementor (I inherited the website as is).

The problem is on the single listing view, eg: `xyz.com/builder/listing-home`

Within that page there is a button that triggers a modal window and that button has a href tag that seems to be referring to some sort of Elementor relative path but it looks like `<a href="%23elementor-action%3Aaction%3Dpopup%3Aopen%26settings%3DeyJpZCI6IjI5NiIsInRvZ2dsZSI6ZmFsc2V9">`

Notice there is no protocol or domain url within the href. And Elementor auto implements this so it's not something I can change by default regarding popup modals.

When the the site is crawled to make sure it is Google compliant for SEO that string in the href gets appended to the page URL, which looks like:

```
xyz.com/builder/listing-home
xyz.com/builder/listing-home/%23elementor-action%3Aaction%3Dpopup%3Aopen%26settings%3DeyJpZCI6IjI5NiIsInRvZ2dsZSI6ZmFsc2V9
xyz.com/builder/listing-home/%23elementor-action%3Aaction%3Dpopup%3Aopen%26settings%3DeyJpZCI6IjI5NiIsInRvZ2dsZSI6ZmFsc2V9/%23elementor-action%3Aaction%3Dpopup%3Aopen%26settings%3DeyJpZCI6IjI5NiIsInRvZ2dsZSI6ZmFsc2V9
xyz.com/builder/listing-home/%23elementor-action%3Aaction%3Dpopup%3Aopen%26settings%3DeyJpZCI6IjI5NiIsInRvZ2dsZSI6ZmFsc2V9/%23elementor-action%3Aaction%3Dpopup%3Aopen%26settings%3DeyJpZCI6IjI5NiIsInRvZ2dsZSI6ZmFsc2V9/%23elementor-action%3Aaction%3Dpopup%3Aopen%26settings%3DeyJpZCI6IjI5NiIsInRvZ2dsZSI6ZmFsc2V9
```

Notice how it loops and just keeps appending and it does it for like 20 times and they all result in 404s, with the exception of the very first one which works and what we want. Not sure how to tackle this but any insight on this issue I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Elementor have a problem with modal triggers URL.

I think it's a bad use of `rawurlencode()`in `create_action_hash()` function in the following file `plugins/elementor/includes/frontend.php`.

I'm affected too on a fresh site and I opened a ticket on Elementor.com. Support confirmed that there're working on a solution...

Waiting from dev team seems the unique option.